# Divisor of the meromorphic differential $\omega=\frac{dx}{y^3}$ on C: $\xi_1^4+\xi_2^4=\xi_0^4$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Consider Fermat's curve of degree 4 defined by C : $\xi_1^4+\xi_2^4=\xi_0^4$ in projective coordinates $(\xi_0 :\xi_1 :\xi_2)$ or, equivalently, by the affine equation $x^4 + y^4 = 1$ in the affine coordinates $(x=\frac{\xi_1}{\xi_0}$, $y=\frac{\xi_2}{\xi_0})$. Show that C is non-singular. Prove that the divisor ($\omega$) of the meromorphic differential $\omega=\frac{dx}{y^3}$ on C: $\xi_1^4+\xi_2^4=\xi_0^4$ consists of 4 points $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, $p_4$ of C at infinity, i.e., lying on the line $\xi_0=0$, each with multiplicity 1; that is, $(\omega) = p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4$. Conclude that the genus of C is $g=3$.

Work:

Let $\xi_0\not=0$ and $x=\frac{\xi_1}{\xi_0}$, $y=\frac{\xi_2}{\xi_0}$. Then we have $\frac{\xi_1^4}{\xi_0^4}+\frac{\xi_2^4}{\xi_0^4}=1$
$\implies$ $F(x,y)=x^4+y^4-1=0$.
Now $F_x=4x^3=0 \iff x=0$ and $F_y=4y^3=0\iff y=0$. But $F(0,0)=1\not=0$ so C is non-singular.

Now we must consider a point at infinity. Let $\xi_0=0$ and we get $\xi_1^4=-\xi_2^4$ which means $\xi_1=(-1)^\frac{1}{4}\xi_2$ where $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}$ stands for $\{e^\frac{-\pi i}{4}, e^\frac{-5\pi i}{4}, e^\frac{-9\pi i}{4},e^\frac{-13\pi i}{4}\}$. So there are four points at infinity: $(0:e^\frac{-\pi i}{4}:1)$, $(0:e^\frac{-5\pi i}{4}:1)$, $(0:e^\frac{-9\pi i}{4}:1)$, and $(0:e^\frac{-13\pi i}{4}:1)$. So consider the point $(0:e^\frac{-\pi i}{4}:1)$. Since $\xi_2\not=0$ the affine coordinates are $v_0=\frac{\xi_0}{\xi_2}$ and $v_1=\frac{\xi_1}{\xi_2}$. So in affine coordinates the curve is $G(v_0,v_1)=v_1^4-v_0^4+1=0$.

So $\frac{\partial G}{\partial v_0}dv_0+\frac{\partial G}{\partial v_1}dv_1=(-4v_0^3)dv_0+(4v_1^3)dv_1=0 \implies dv_0=\frac{v_1^3}{v_0^3}dv_1 $.

Now, we have $x=\frac{\xi_1}{\xi_0}=\frac{v_1}{v_0}$ and $y=\frac{\xi_2}{\xi_0}=\frac{1}{v_0}$. So $\omega=\frac{dx}{y^3}=v_0^3d(\frac{v_1}{v_0})=v_0^3(\frac{dv_1}{v_0}-\frac{v_1}{v_0^2}dv_0)=v_0^2dv_1-(v_0 v_1 )dv_0=v_0^2 dv_1-(v_1 v_0)(\frac{v_1^3}{v_0^3})dv_1=\dots = \frac{v_0^3-v_1^4}{v_0^2} dv_1$

But we know $v_0^4-v_1^4=1$ so,

$\omega=\frac{1}{v_0^2}dv_1$

From this point I am not sure how to determine the four points that would form the divisor of $\omega$. I think I can use $Pl\ddot{u}cker's$ Formula, $2-2g=d(3-d)$, with $d=4$ to show that the genus of C is $g=3$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The point $(0:0:1)$  you call "at infinity" is not on your curve.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Okay, so do I need to find a point that is on the curve when $\xi_0=0$? This would be when $\xi_1^4=-\xi_2^4$ or $\xi_1=(-1)^\frac{1}{4}\xi_2$. So the point(s) at infinity would be $(0:(-1)^\frac{1}{4}:1)$? If this is true, can I still use affine coordinates when $\xi_2\not=0$?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg By $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}$ I mean $\pm(\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt(2)})$. As for the new coordinates, aren't the subscripts on the new coordinates arbitrary? Does this different point at infinity chnage the work I have done to find $\omega$?

Comment: Alternatively, $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}$ is equivalent to  $\{e^\frac{-\pi i}{4}, e^\frac{-5\pi i}{4},e^\frac{-9\pi i}{4},e^\frac{-13\pi i}{4}\}$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, this question is from my second complex analysis course

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  meromorphic form $\omega$ has no poles and its only zeros are at the four points $P _i$ whose  homogeneous coordinates $(\xi_0:\xi_1:\xi_2)$ are $(0:a_i:1)$, where the $a_i$ 's are the  complex solutions of  the equation $z^4=-1$.
In the coordinates $v_0,v_1$ the differential form $\omega$ becomes $\omega=v_0^2dv_1-v_0v_1dv_0$ and at the points $P_i$ (whose coordinates $(v_0,v_1)$ are $(0,a_i)$) a uniformizing parameter is $v_0$.
Hence at $P_i$ we write $$\omega =v_0^2(\frac{v_0^3}{v_1^3})dv_0-v_0v_1dv_0$$ and this shows (since $v_1(P_i)\neq 0$) that the divisor $\operatorname {div}(\omega)$ has multiplicity $1$ at $P_i$ and that finally $$\operatorname {div}(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^4 1\cdot P_i        $$
This is in line with the formula $\operatorname {deg}(\operatorname {div}(\omega))=2g-2=2.3-2=4$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Once I figured out what the proper points at infinity should be, it made a lot more sense.